# How to integrate Nokogiri in Rails App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen, nokogiri

I'm trying to integrate Nokogiri in my app in Rails 3.2. I have watched Rails Casts episode and tried creating a test file called nokogiri_test.rb and then run it through my cmd. It worked fine and fetch the content from a travel site.

The app i am building is a travel website in rails as an experiment. I want to fetch the information from another travel website eg: A para about travel to Asia.

I don't understand how to implement the Nokogiri code in my app. Do i need to create a controller and then write the nokogiri code in it? or write the nokogiri code in the existing controller pages or elsewhere? And then i also want to display the info in my view (asia.html.erb). How do i display it?

I have searched everywhere online and never found a solution. Can anybody shed some light? I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general convention is not to put any business logic into controllers or views. Especially if any third-party services (like external websites) are involved. You can may follow the suggestion of [Rails Casts "Screen Scraping"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri) and build a rake task of put the scraping into a model.

Comment: That means i need to write the info to a model and then display it in the view from the model?

Comment: Yes, build a model, instantiate in the controller and show this instance in the view. Caching usually makes a lot of sense in this scenario. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: But then how does screen scrapping reduce work? I was thinking of fetching the info directly from the external website without involving model(db). If a db is involved, it is as good as you create a model and store custom info and display.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit fuzzy with my wording. I don't mean an ActiveRecord model. Instead i mean a ruby class.

Comment: Thanks so much. But i do have a question. I have written a rake task now. To show it in my view how do i call? I need to display it in the page i created (asia.html.erb), how do i do that? forgive me if i am slow in understanding.

Comment: This is the rake task i wrote: desc "fetch asia info"
task :asia_info => :environment do
  require 'nokogiri'  
  require 'open-uri' 

    url = "http://www.lonelyplanet.com/europe"  
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))  
    asia = doc.at_css("p").text 
end  How to display it in the view?

Answer (score 1):

I see that this question isn't solved yet around here. I had the same problem, and many searchs (and a lot of headaches) after, I found the solution: [Display data scraped from Nokogiri in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487198/display-data-scraped-from-nokogiri-in-rails)

So (don't know about the general convention), it is possible to put your nokogiri's web **scraper** in your controller! (I'm a beggniner too)
Hope this will help